# How do I stop Java/Eclipse from bleeding stdout and stderr together?

Tags: java, eclipse, stdout, stderr

So this is the output I'm getting in the program I'm working on:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
CreationDate
getCreationDate
setCreationDate
LastModifiedDate
getLastModifiedDate
setLastModifiedDate
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at Transform.transform(Transform.java:86)
    at Experiment.main(Experiment.java:120)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at Transform.transform(Transform.java:86)
    at Experiment.main(Experiment.java:120)
DeletionDate
getDeletionDate
setDeletionDate
```

The code calling it:

```
    for (Field f : databaseFields) {
        String upperCamelCase = Character.toUpperCase(f.getName().charAt(0)) + f.getName().substring(1);
        System.out.println(upperCamelCase);

        String getMethodName = "get" + upperCamelCase;
        System.out.println(getMethodName);

        Method getMethod = null;
        try {
            getMethod = databaseClass.getDeclaredMethod(getMethodName);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { 
        } catch (SecurityException e) { }

        if (getMethod == null) {
            getMethodName = "is" + upperCamelCase;
            try {
                getMethod = databaseClass.getDeclaredMethod(getMethodName);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                continue;
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        String setMethodName = "set" + upperCamelCase;
        System.out.println(setMethodName);
        Method setMethod = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.length; i++) {
            try {
                setMethod = jsonClass.getDeclaredMethod(setMethodName, parameterTypes[i]);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { }
        }

        if (setMethod == null) {
            continue;
        }

        try {
            setMethod.invoke(jsonObject, getMethod.invoke(databaseObject));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is for a reflection transform, and obviously I can't tell which of the get or set methods it's throwing an exception on. How can I fix this?

Comment: Left click on the Experiment or Transform in parenthesis to jump to the line of code that caused the abend.  In this case, line 86 of Transform, called by line 120 of Experiment.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I added the code. Line 86 is the `setMethod.invoke`. The `println`s above are all of the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call

```
System.out.flush();
```

after each `println` call to force the output to the console immediately.

Comment: I'm so mad that I didn't ask in my question, "Is there an equivalent to `cin.flush()` in Java?" Because that's what I was thinking. I thought it would sound dumb if I mentioned an input class for an output problem though.

Comment: I had to add `System.err.flush()` after each of the stack traces, but it worked!

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse, stderr and stdout in Console are colored differently. You can also hide one or the other by right-clicking on console window and selecting Preferences.

In command line, you can use redirects `>` and `2>` to send stderr or stdout to separate file.

Comment: Well the problem is I don't want to/need to separate them. I need some way of telling which line of stdout corresponds to the exception coming from stderr.